# Ubuntu 15.10 updates - Failed to download repository information - check internet connection

Tags: networking, updates, internet, repository

I had previous problems like this, first it did not want to update anything. It always sad:

### Failed to download repository information check your internet connection,

but i have internet connection and i discovered just to uncheck the PPA packadges that caused the problem and i successfully update all my software.
After that a exclamation mark in triangular sign appeard next to Wifi icon that says:

### The update information is outdated. This may be caused by network problems or by a repository that is no longer available. Please update manually by selecting 'Show updates' from the indicator menu, and watching for any failing repositories.

After clicking on that it says your software is up to date, but when i try to press update it's checking for cache and says, as always, FAILED TO DOWNLOAD REPOSITORY INFORMATION CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION.

Is this problem with a wirelles driver, or some packadges that needs to be removed? Solutions? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have reputation to comment so..)

This may be because you don't have Internet access. When I installed ubuntu 15.10, I also faced similar problems. Was unable to access Internet even though I was connected to wifi. So to solve this you may do as follows(if you have not done this already) :

```
Click on wifi icon on top panel. 
Click on edit connection. 
Choose your connection and press edit 
Now, add 8.8.8.8 as your additional dns
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks but this is not working, parallel to this some packadges are making problems with apt-get update. Also that somebody that has problem with my post i can assure you i've tryed 'solutions' on those pages